# Saving multi-line with variables string to html file

Tags: python, html

I have function in python that takes few strings and should join them with a bigger string that should be a html file.

```
def manzy(product_name, product_image, product_price_new, product_price_before):
a = """  <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>title</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="maincss.css">
              </head>
              <body>

                    <div class="shop-card">
                      <div class="title"> """ + product_name + """ </div>


                      <div class="desc">
                            Womans cloath
                      </div>
                      <div class="slider">
                            <figure data-color="#E24938, #A30F22 "> 
                              <img src=""" +  product_image + """/>
                            </figure>
                      </div>

                      <div class="cta">
                            <div class="price"> """ + product_price_new + """</div><br>
                            <div class="price"> """ + product_price_before + """</div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg"></div>

            </div>

              </body>
            </html> """

Html_file= open("filename","w")
Html_file.write(a)
Html_file.close()
```

When i get the code running, the file gets created and then I get error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 400: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have read few topics on this subject and I am worried that my error has something to do with joining function arguments with this mess of a string. However, the error does not say anything about me messing the format of the string, and maybe there is something with that?

Comment: In the code you posted is no `u'\xe7'` ...

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Its in one of them function inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Python (before version 3, according to my own tests), didn't like UTF-8 for output, so you're limited by default to use ASCII

```
a = u'\xe7'
print(a) # Throws the error on Python 1 and 2, works fine on Python 3
```

Here are the tests: [Python 1](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/z/P1HBVqFUPaYi1Vydq6AoM69EI1Hz/38A), [Python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1HBVqFUPaYi1Vydq6AoM69EI1Hz/38A), [Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBVqFUPaYi1Vydq6AoM69EI1Hz/38A)

Anyway, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Html_file.write(a.encode('utf-8'))
```

Here are the tests for `print` working with this fix: [Python 1](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/z/P1HBVqFUPaYi1Vydq6AoM69EI1EvNS85PyVVQ720JE3XQl1T8/9/AA), [Python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1HBVqFUPaYi1Vydq6AoM69EI1EvNS85PyVVQ720JE3XQl1T8/9/AA)